# Connect AWS EKS through AWS Cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I'm trying to get the information of EKS clusters like nodes, pods, etc.. through AWS Cli But I couldn't get any commands.

Answer (score 1):

```
export PATH=/Users/username/Library/Python/3.6/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

works for me

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this is the only commands that aws cli support - [AWS EKS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/eks/index.html), These commands are not a replacement for kubectl commands,And they are meant to get information about eks managed service.

Be aware that If your aws cli version is lower than 1.16.232, use [Installing the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-install.html) in order to update.

Comment: Thank You I'll try with the links and get back to you.

Comment: Sure , Let me know if you have any other issues.

Comment: Hi I refer the links and successfully installed the EKS but again I'm getting an error saying ("Unable to connect to the server: getting credentials: exec: exec: "heptio-authenticator-aws": executable file not found in $PATH") while executing the command related to kubectl

Comment: You should replace heptio-authenticator-aws with aws-iam-authenticator in your kubeconfig file.
https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator/issues/132

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following to make sure you can connect to EKS through `kubectl`

1 -  Install `aws-iam-authenticator`, it will help authenticating to EKS cluster,  here's how to [install it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/install-aws-iam-authenticator.html)

2 - Make sure you have AWS CLI version 1.16.308 or greater as it uses internally eks's `get-token` command.

3 - Modify your `kubectl` configuration file to use for authentication. To create your `kubeconfig` file by AWS CLI, run the following command that will auto-generate `kubeconfig` and store or merge generated config under `~/.kube/config`. For More information, please check [official documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-kubeconfig.html)

`aws eks --region region update-kubeconfig --name cluster_name`

4- To test, run `kubectl get svc`